# How to find word with en dash within it?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to find and highlight all words combinations with en dash within it in MS Word document.
For example in the sentence: "In the years 1993–1996 the economic situation was difficult." macro should result with highlighting "1993–1996".

I tried to use several text combinations with wildcards but it was not successful.

```
Sub DSFinder()

Dim r As Range

'highlights incorrect'
Set r = ActiveDocument.Range
With r.Find
.MatchWildcards = True
.Text = "*(^0150)*"
Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
r.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink
Loop
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `<[a-z0-9]@^=[a-z0-9]@>` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a *wildcard* Find with:

```
.Text = "<[! ]@^=*>"
```

PS: The following code is much more efficient than what you're using:

```
Sub DSFinder()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim iDx As Long
iDx = Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdPink
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Text = "<[! ]@^=*>"
  .Replacement.Text = "^&"
  .Replacement.Highlight = True
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = iDx
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm new to VBA. I got a few macros for small modifications, but I guess I actually have to read in and redo it the way you suggested.